# Storing an Element in Array (Java) until I type something to stop it

Tags: java, arrays, input, output

I'm doing this project with Java and I'm trying to do some calculations and add it to an array so I can output all the elements from this array when I type '-1' but it keeps calling the function even when I type '-1'
(I'm starting to learn Java)

```
public class main {
    
    public static double computeIncome(double SalesAmount) {
        double num = SalesAmount;
        double baseSalary = 5000;
        double numTotal = baseSalary;
        
        if(num < 5000.01) {
            numTotal += num * 0.08;
        }
        else {
            if(num < 10000.01) {
                numTotal += ((num - 5000) * 0.10);
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.08;
            }
            else {
                numTotal += ((num - 10000) * 0.12);
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.10;
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.08;
                
            }
        }
        return numTotal;
    }
        
        
    
    static void cd(int DataCount, double[] DataBase) {
        int dataCount = 0;
        double[] db = DataBase;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double x = computeIncome(reader.nextDouble());
        
        
        if(x != -1) { 
            db[dataCount] = x;
            dataCount += 1;
            cd(dataCount, db);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {  
                    System.out.println(db[i] + " ");  
               }  
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dataCount = 0;
        double[] db = new double[20];
        System.out.println("Input the sales: (type '-1' to finish )");
        cd(dataCount, db);
            
    }
}
```

So when I type -1 it just keep calling a function even tho I already implemented an else function
I know this should be an easy one and a simple code but I feel like I'm making my life really hard with this piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a bit - fixed some logic and renamed arguments according to Java standart. I believe now it does what you expected:

```
    public class main {

    public static double computeIncome(double salesAmount) {
        double num = salesAmount;
        double baseSalary = 5000;
        double numTotal = baseSalary;

        if(num < 5000.01) {
            numTotal += num * 0.08;
        }
        else {
            if(num < 10000.01) {
                numTotal += ((num - 5000) * 0.10);
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.08;
            }
            else {
                numTotal += ((num - 10000) * 0.12);
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.10;
                numTotal += baseSalary * 0.08;

            }
        }
        return numTotal;
    }

    static void cd(int dataCount, double[] dataBase) {
        int currentDataCount = dataCount;
        double[] db = dataBase;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        double valueFromInput = reader.nextDouble();
        if (valueFromInput == -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(db[i] + " ");
            }
        }

        double x = computeIncome(valueFromInput);
        db[currentDataCount] = x;
        currentDataCount += 1;
        cd(currentDataCount, db);

        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dataCount = 0;
        double[] db = new double[20];
        System.out.println("Input the sales: (type '-1' to finish )");
        cd(dataCount, db);
    }
}
```

*class also should be renamed to Main(Java class names should start with capital letter). I can show how to improve this code further, if you like

Comment: Yes, this would be the proper solution for what I wanted to do... Any thoughts on how can I just create the number of elements that I need on the array for the execution? For example, If I only use 4 elements, typing -1 to stop It would also input the number of arrays that I declared

Comment: You can replace double array with ArrayList<Double> it is much more convenient than array. You can initialize it with ArrayList<Double>myArray = new ArrayList(); and then use add() method to add elements to it